# Should (or will) a proposed site's "Great On-Topic Example" questions be automatically included in its beta?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, beta-phase, example-questions

I've read some great on-topic example questions on Area 51.

My questions:

- Should a proposed site's "Great On-Topic Example" questions be automatically included in its beta?
- Will a proposed site's "Great On-Topic Example" questions be automatically included in its beta?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.

Because all that exists of the question is the title and perhaps a comment or two of clarification.

For the question to be useful on the site it will have to have all the details that would enable someone to answer it correctly.

That doesn't mean that those who proposed questions for the site shouldn't post the full question - in fact that's what I'm going attempt to do with the sites I've signed up to.

Comment: And it's not like we don't know how to copy paste...

Comment: @Ivo - and for those who don't know, there's always Super User :-]