# When a site passes from commit phase to beta phase, are the good question examples automatically created?

Tags: support, area-51, beta-phase, example-questions

When a Q&A site passed from commit phase to beta phase, are the questions that have been marked as *good example* be automatically created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Looking at one of the sites passed to beta phase, I had the impression it was what happens.

Comment: @kiam A lot of the example questions are things that the user actually intends to ask, so they ask it when the beta comes out. Other times, it's something another user would ask, so they snipe it for themselves. But there's nothing automatic.

Comment: See my answer to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55105/should-or-will-a-proposed-sites-great-on-topic-example-questions-be-automati