# Shouldn't the questions proposed in Area51 definition stage be added and attributed to the user who proposed them?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, definition-phase, private-beta

One site I was following on Area 51 just went into beta, and I had a couple questions in the top ten "example questions" during the definition stage, but when I looked at my account, I had no questions. I searched for the question, and someone had already asked it, thus stealing my reputation.

Does anyone else think this isn't fair?

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55105/should-or-will-a-proposed-sites-great-on-topic-example-questions-be-automati and ChrisF's answer - all there is will be a title and comments, but no actual question body!

Answer (score 7):

No, because they're just example questions.

All Area51 is about, is to figure out what kind of questions you would like to see there. The fact that people voted on your question, just means that they think it's a good example. You should be proud of that!

Besides, you should see it as an encouragement to ask more of these questions, because obviously others thought they were good too.

Comment: Further, several example questions are terribly generic - "Is X model better than Y model for rain climate research?" would be perfectly fine to ask in area51 without specifying X or Y, but makes no sense on the real site.  The purpose of posting the question is different between the definition of the site, and the beta of the site.