# Why are example questions gathered during the definition stage not visible during the beta?

Tags: discussion, area-51

I understand the rationale of not automatically populating a beta site with example questions, as defined here: [Shouldn't the questions proposed in Area51 definition stage be added and attributed to the user who proposed them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73972/shouldnt-the-questions-proposed-in-area51-definition-stage-be-added-and-attribu)

That said, I don't understand the rationale of not having those questions being visible or even retrievable once a site enters beta.  Sometimes, people want to contribute, but don't know exactly how. By seeing example questions, other questions may be sparked - or even those questions might be asked as learning questions.

Additionally, (and especially for closed sites), the example questions show what *didn't* work.

So, what is the counter-case?  Why should the example questions be hidden from view for eternity, once a site hits beta?

Comment: I don't know that we really want to encourage people to copy down questions they don't actually have just to have some questions on the site. Such questions are almost certainly going to lack detail and be pretty bad, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are visible, go to the "definition" tab of the area51 page.

For example, [here are the example questions of the currently-in-beta "Beer" site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48905?phase=definition)

Comment: Wow.  That was hidden to me.  I didn't realize you could see each tab and click on it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Questions from the definition stage are very often not good questions to ask. They establish the topic, but often they are too imprecise or artificial to work as Stack Exchange questions, because there's only so much you can cram in one sentence. The definition stage calls for question titles more than questions.

Furthermore people typically ask questions on Stack Exchange because they want an answer now. Conversely, when someone writes an example question on Area 51, they know that they won't be getting an answer. Questions on Area 51 are what someone expects to see on the site, not what someone wants answered.

The example questions are not hidden for eternity. Starting from the commitment phase, you can still read them by selecting the “definition” tab on the site proposal. They are low-key, and that's how it should be.

Example questions are not a good indicator of why a closed site failed. The questions that were actually asked on the site, as well as the meta discussions, are more important. These are only made available as an archive file that you can download.